# How to say something is official by legal status?

Tags: synonyms

*With Sara recently changing her last name and now Sam’s changing as well, we are an official, `legally defined`, family.*

My goal here is to say that by law, Sara and Sam are now an official family in the eyes of the law.

What is a better way to say this?

Comment: I doubt many if any countries have a legal definition of a "family", nor do I see why a surname change (informal or by deed poll in the UK) would affect such classification. So I think it's a matter of opinion how one might describe whatever process OP is referring to.

Comment: As FF notes, you might want to choose a different example, as the scenario presented doesn't make any sense, at least not in the Five Eyes countries (among others). Regardless, a common way to distinguish between law and practice is to use the legal terms [*de jure* and *de facto*](https://onlinelaw.wustl.edu/blog/legal-english-de-factode-jure/).

Comment: [Official](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/official) already carries that sense. (Or is there an *official* but *non-legal / para-legal / illegal* sort?)

Comment: Most societies accept that marriage and childbirth are the usual process to create families; are you referring to adoption ?

Comment: I was in fact referring to adoption in this scenario. Saying “now an official Family” seems like it holds a perspective that they were not a family before then. While it’s true they were always Family, I didn’t know how to say it’s official without making it sound like the prior time was not defined as Family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume (from comments in the question) that Sara and Sam are children being adopted. It's quite likely that the children were already part of the family, probably by way of an official fostering arrangement.

Already being a *de-facto* family and becoming a *de-jure* family (also from comments) means that all that is necessary is to acknowledge the legal recognition of adoption.

You can use the word *officially* for that.

> **officially**
>   In an official manner or capacity; by virtue, or in consequence, of one's office; by or in presence of an official; with official authority, sanction, or formality. Now frequently in contexts implying a contrast with other some truth or actuality: **in public and for official purposes, but not necessarily in reality.**
>
> > 1976   ‘B. Shelby’ *Great Pebble Affair* i. 30   Officially, I had been renting my apartment for three months before I even saw it.
>
> [OED]

> With Sara recently changing her last name and now Sam’s changing as well, we are officially a family.

In British English this use of *officially* does have a slight whiff of sarcasm: you know you don't need official recognition for the family to be a family; but the State may well feel it does, so you comply. It's sarcastic because it's taking the OED definition I've bolded and turning it on its head. It recognises that the family was a family before, and they simply have some piece of paper now, too.

Answer (score 0):

Changing one's name has no bearing on the status of legal relationship.  It is neither necessary nor sufficient to create legal rights or duties as spouses or parent-child or otherwise.  So your sentence makes no sense.  There are different definitions of "family" in laws and regulations for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Two other suggestions occur to me.

When something is done with established legal forms and requirements, or more generally done according to recognized principles or accepted rules and standards, we say that it is *[legitimate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legitimate)*. For example, children whose parents are a married couple are called ***legitimate children***.

When we want to say that something is true in terms of the law, we can say that it is true ***legally***. This need not refer to what is permitted or forbidden by the law. For example, people commonly say that someone is [*legally blind*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/legally%20blind), not to suggest that in some other case blindness might violate the law, but rather to suggest that he is blind in some legal sense.

P.S. Not only *can* you use the word ***officially*** for that; you *did* use the word ***officially*** for that. "My goal here is to say that by law, Sara and Sam are now an official family..."